# Looking for a neat way to separate string

Tags: java, string

I have a string like "cat,dog,fish,elephant" and I want to exclude the first elements by delimiter (which is cat) and get a return of string "dog,fish,elephant". Is there a java library that can do this in a neat way?

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean?

```
String dfe = "cat,dog,fish,elephant".split(",", 2)[1];
```

Note: this will produce an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException if there is no `,`

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
String s = "cat,dog,fish,elephant";
String result = s.substring(1 + s.indexOf(','));
```

`result` is the original `String` if there is no comma.